# Rich client interactivity with JQuery etc - most robust approach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, telerik

Any views on the most robust tools to implement a pretty 'client rich' (ie charts/controls updating one another's content without postback).  I have used Telerik quite a bit, but it seems very markup heavy when you want to configure it for ajax calls and controls updating each other on the client side.

The other options seem to be $ajax commands in jquery, standard updatepanels or a hybrid approach.  Maintainability/simplicity is important.  So is performance though - if simple JSON can pass rather than viewstates etc, that would be preferable.

Thanks

Mark

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the responses.  The nature of my question is more around 'architecture'.  In the sense of driving things from client side events (ie when dropdown A changes, use client side events to refresh the others) or using server side events to 'plumb' it all together and then render any inline javascript from that side.  Hope that clarifies it a bit.  Thanks

Comment: See the MVC framework I mentioned.  You can use jQuery to post back to a controller and return just what's called a PartialView and update sections of the page.  Very neat, quick and easy to code

Comment: Thanks for that.  I did an MVC tute about 6 months ago and it didn't meld well with my brain (or my Telerik components which I use quite a bit).  I keep hearing about it though so may need to revisit MVC.  I seem to spend more time keeping up with what new framework there is than actually developing stuff!  Welcome to the MS ecosystem I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for Free stuff;

http://www.highcharts.com/ is probably the best free jQuery charting out there.  It's brilliant in what it can do.

I also use http://jqueryui.com/ for a lot of my UI needs as it contains most of the controls I use in every site I write.

jQuery has a great AJAX implementation and if you use it in conjunction with the [MVC framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc) you have a really smooth UX.

**edit**

jQuery

```
$.get("/userControls/PrintRunPriceCalculator.ashx?pages=" + pages + "&quantity=" + quantity, {}, function (data) {
    if (data != "")
        $(".TotalAmountFigure").html(data);
});
```

ashx

```
public class PrintRunPriceCalculator : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState, IBookPrintDetail
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int quantity;
        int pages;

        try
        {
            quantity = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["quantity"]);
            pages = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["pages"]);
        }catch{ return; }

        BookPrintDetailPresenter presenter = new BookPrintDetailPresenter(this);
        context.Response.Write(presenter.GetQuote(quantity, pages));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  Yes, highcharts is the very splinter in my foot leading me to this question.  Most of what I've done previously has been server/codebehind stuff, but Highcharts brings you into the client side pretty abruptly.  The question then becomes, should I setup the logic in my other dropdowns/etc in javascript and call 'custom made' webservice functions to do updates/data changes.  Or is this just re-inventing the wheel and I should stay largely to server side except for the bits directly related to highcharts?  A conundrum!

Comment: Yes that is a pretty pickle.  personally i'd ajax everything i could out to an ashx if using asp.net or a controller if mvc.  only updating what needs to be updated makes some sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into ashx's.  The simplest way I've found so far is creating an asmx webservice and decorating the methods with the [WebMethod] attribute.  Do you think ashx is a better way to go?

Comment: Not a better way just another way.  read my edit for how I do it.

Comment: Many thanks!  I notice the ProcessRequest method isn't mentioned in the call - does it just default to the single method that's there?

Comment: yeah.  from there switch on a querystring value to call other methods

Comment: An additional note to make here, since you mentioned ASP.NET MVC. Because you're already using Telerik (for ASP.NET AJAX) you might already have their MVC Extensions depending on what licenses you own. Could be worth checking out for some additional UI components: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx. Works great with jQuery so would fit in with the other solutions mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for that Carl.  Yep, I'm super comfy with webforms but all opinions seem to say if you want to use jquery and frameworks, MVC is much wiser.  I'll be sad to see the end of my easily implemented server controls if I make that move though :( Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should look past jQuery into things like backbone.js or even sproutcore.

---

Edit: Yeah, what you are looking for is exactly what Backbone.js does 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-started-with-backbone-js/

Comment: Thanks for the link to Sproutcore, I wasn't aware of that one!

Comment: @Wes, not sure backbone is a replacement for jQuery.  This from their site.  "Does it replace jQuery?

No. They’re pretty complementary in their scopes with almost no overlaps in functionality."

Comment: ahah yeah wtf, just trying to help people out